# Can you automatically attach Eclipse’s debugger to subprocess?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Is it possible to automatically attach the Eclipse debugger when I launch a Java process? I’m running a program that spawns processes (using RMI Activation) and I give the subprocess an argv containing `-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=9000`, and then I tell Eclipse to connect to the remote application using a saved debug configuration. But it’s somewhat tedious to click Debug every time a process is spawned. Is there a way to automatically tell Eclipse to open a new connection?

Answer (score 0):

If the debug process is the last process you have launched. You can use F11 to restart it.

But if search something really automatic, then you need to write a plugin in Eclipse. First check if it doesn't exist :
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/